# Locales and encoding

Tags: locale, encoding

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="ru_UA:ru"
$ locale -a | grep ru_UA
ru_UA.iso885915
ru_UA.utf8
```

I want to have:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="ru_UA:ru"

$ locale -a | grep ru_UA
ru_UA.iso885915
ru_UA.koi8r
ru_UA.utf8
```

That is, I want to add one more encoding `ru_UA.koi8r` for the locale `ru_UA`.

How do I bring the system to the form? Advice please!

Answer (score 0):

First, `locale -a | grep ru_RU` will never return what you write. Maybe `locale -a | grep ru_UA`.

Second, you  can generate new locales by issuing:

```
sudo locale-gen ru_UA.KOI8-R
```

I didn't check if `ru_UA.KOI8-R` is the exact form for what you wish.

More about: [(Re-)Generating locales](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#A.28Re-.29Generating_locales).

Comment: ppm@ppm-VirtualBox ~ $ sudo locale-gen ru_UA.koi8r
[sudo] password for ppm: 
ppm@ppm-VirtualBox ~ $ locale -a | grep ru_UA
ru_UA.iso885915
ru_UA.utf8
ppm@ppm-VirtualBox ~ $ sudo locale-gen ru_UA.KOI8-R
ppm@ppm-VirtualBox ~ $ locale -a | grep ru_UA
ru_UA.iso885915
ru_UA.utf8
ppm@ppm-VirtualBox ~ $

Comment: @Igor I told you, check for exact form of encoding for `ru_UA.KOI8-R`

Comment: @Igor I think is `ru_RU.KOI8-R` or something like this... Try yourself with many variants until you get it.

Comment: But look more closely output of the command I tried koi8r and KOI8-R

Comment: @Igor I don't understand what you mean. I sow that didn't give any result and I told you what you can do.

Comment: @Igor And check the link that I gave it.

Comment: sudo localedef -f KOI-8-R -i ru_UA ru_UA.KOI8-R

Comment: @Igor No, you didn't understood. This command is working like this: `sudo locale-gen <encoding>`. Replace `<encoding>` with what character encoding do you wish (should be something valid).

Comment: No. I get it.But locale-gen ru_UA.KOI8-R and locale-gen koi8r did not produce the effect.
But localedef led to the result

Comment: @Igor Ok, if you solved the problem, you should accept the answer and I will update with what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide which encoding to use; you cannot enable both concurrently.

That said, and since you ask for advice, I would advise you to not use any other locale but UTF-8 locales in Ubuntu. If you do, you may encounter unexpected behaviour in many respects.